# Get all headers and resursively create a tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a tree using headers.

Example:

```
<h1>Wow</h1>
<h2>Blablablub</h2>
<p>Lorem Ipsum...</p>
<h1>Lalalala</h1>
<p>Lorem Ipsum...</p>
<h1>Ble</h1>
<h2>Test</h2>
<h3>Third</h3>
<p>Lorem Ipsum...</p>
```

This list should be created:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a>Wow</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a>Blablablub</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>Lalalala</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>Ble</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a>Test</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a>Third</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

`a` tags should have a custom id but that isn't important for this question. I tried to do this but I couldn't figure it out. Here's what I tried:

```
function find_titles(find_num, element, prefix=""){
        temp_list = $("<ul></ul>");
        element.find(`${prefix}h${find_num}`).each(function(i, object){
            let text = $(object).text();
            let id = text.replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/gi, "") + random_chars();

            $(object).attr("id", id);

            if ($(object).next().prop("tagName").toLowerCase() == `h${find_num + 1}`){
                console.log($(object));
                next_titles = find_titles(find_num + 1, $(object), "+ ")[0].innerHTML;
            } else {
                next_titles = "";
            }

            $(`<li><a href="#${id}">${text}</a>${next_titles}</li>`).appendTo(temp_list);
        });
        return temp_list;
    }
```

**EDIT**

This:

```
<h1>First</h1>
<h2>Second</h2>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<h3>Third</h3>
```

Should be normally converted into this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a>First</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a>Second</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>Third</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I don't care wether the first is a `h1` `h2` or a `h3`. In the text it's only important for styling but in the tree it isn't important.

Comment: what about `h3`, `h4` ...? why `Third h2` is the child of `second h2`?

Comment: Oh that was a mistake. I meant `h3`

Comment: what if it would be `h1`, `h2`, `p`, `h3`? Better you post more details

Comment: yeah.... This shouldn't happen but if this happens it should start on h3 again as a self cycle. I will add an example.

Comment: what if `h1`, `h1`- should be separate one or as a child?

Comment: Does it have to be derived from HTML? you can model your data as a tree, i.e: `{ content: {
  title: 'First',
content: {
  title: 'Second',
  content: {
    title: 'third'
  }
}
} }`;

and iterate over that structure?

Comment: Why isnt `<h3>Third</h3>` nested inside `<a>Second</a`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first clear your data to get only `heading` nodes and their number and text. After that you can loop the data and build tree structure based on levels using array and index number for each level.

```js
function tree(data) {
  data = Array.from(data).reduce((r, e) => {
    const number = e.nodeName.match(/\d+?/g);
    if(number) r.push({ text: e.textContent, level: +number })
    return r;
  }, [])

  const result = $("<ul>")
  const levels = [
    [], result
  ]

  data.forEach(({ level, text }) => {
    const li = $("<li>")
    const a = $("<a>", { text, href: text })
    levels[level + 1] = $('<ul>')

    li.append(a)
    li.append(levels[level + 1]);

    levels[level].append(li)
  })

  return result;
}

const result = tree($("body > *"));
$("body").html(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Wow</h1>
<h2>Blablablub</h2>
<p>Lorem Ipsum...</p>
<h1>Lalalala</h1>
<p>Lorem Ipsum...</p>
<h1>Ble</h1>
<h2>Test</h2>
<h3>Third</h3>
<p>Lorem Ipsum...</p>
```

You could also do this in one `reduce` method and add to tree if the element is heading.

```js
function tree(data) {
  const result = $("<ul>")
  const levels = [
    [], result
  ]

  Array.from(data).reduce((r, { textContent: text, nodeName }) => {
    const number = nodeName.match(/\d+?/g);
    const level = number ? +number : null;

    if(level) {
      const li = $('<li>').append($("<a>", { text, href: text }))
      r.push({ level: r[level + 1] = $('<ul>') })
      r[level].append(li.append(levels[level + 1]))
    }

    return r;
  }, levels)

  return result;
}

const result = tree($("body > *"));
$("body").html(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Wow</h1>
<h2>Blablablub</h2>
<p>Lorem Ipsum...</p>
<h1>Lalalala</h1>
<p>Lorem Ipsum...</p>
<h1>Ble</h1>
<h2>Test</h2>
<h3>Third</h3>
<p>Lorem Ipsum...</p>
```

Comment: It fails with the second test case

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through all the `H1` elements and then iterate through all the next header elements (all except `H1`). Here is an example:

```js
const elements = $('h1').map(function() {
  let container = $('<li>');
  const ret = container;

  container.append($('<a>').text($(this).text()));

  let next = $(this).next('h2, h3, h4, h5');

  while (next.length) {
    const tmp = $('<li>');
    tmp.append($('<a>').text(next.text()));
    container.append(tmp);
    container = tmp;
    next = next.next('h2, h3, h4, h5');
  }
  return ret;
}).get();

const parent = $('<ul>');
parent.append(elements);

console.log(parent[0].innerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Wow</h1>
<h2>Blablablub</h2>
<p>Lorem Ipsum...</p>
<h1>Lalalala</h1>
<p>Lorem Ipsum...</p>
<h1>Ble</h1>
<h2>Test</h2>
<h3>Third</h3>
<p>Lorem Ipsum...</p>
```

Comment: It fails with the second test case

Answer (score 1):

Using [`:header`](https://api.jquery.com/header-selector/) selector and [`tagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName) property

```js
let $sub, $ul = $('<ul/>')

$(':header').each(function() {
  let $this = $(this),
      $prev = $this.prev(':header'),
      $parent = $prev.length && $prev.prop('tagName') < $this.prop('tagName') ? $sub : $ul
      
  $parent.append('<li><a>' + $this.text() + '</a></li>')
  $sub = $('<ul/>').appendTo($parent.find('li:last'))
})

$('body').html($ul)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Wow</h1>
<h2>Blablablub</h2>
<p>Lorem Ipsum...</p>
<h1>Lalalala</h1>
<p>Lorem Ipsum...</p>
<h1>Ble</h1>
<h2>Test</h2>
<h3>Third</h3>
<h3>Third</h3>
<p>Lorem Ipsum...</p>
<h1>First</h1>
<h2>Second</h2>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<h3>Third</h3>

<h1>First</h1>
<h2>Second</h2>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<h3>Third</h3>
```